# I cannot understand this PHP code syntax from AWS library

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I am trying to understand the code from Amazon  AWS PHP library and while I was reading it I saw an unfamiliar syntax I've never seen before. 
Here is an example of a code that's inside a class method and yet somehow uses the keywords `static` and `use`.

I always thought that you use `use` only at the beginning of the php file and the word `static` is only used to indicate that a class method should only be called statically.

```
        $resolver = static function (
            CommandInterface $c
        ) use ($api, $provider, $name, $region, $version) {
            if (!empty($c['@context']['signing_region'])) {
                $region = $c['@context']['signing_region'];
            }
            $authType = $api->getOperation($c->getName())['authtype'];
            switch ($authType){
                case 'none':
                    $version = 'anonymous';
                    break;
                case 'v4-unsigned-body':
                    $version = 'v4-unsigned-body';
                    break;
            }
            return SignatureProvider::resolve($provider, $version, $name, $region);
        };
```

Comment: I think this is a very interesting question. It may be off-topic, I’m not sure... But where else would one go to find this? I’ve not seen it in the docs. But it adds value to this site. Perhaps the drive-by down-voters could shed a little light on this. (But I’m not going to hold my breath)

Comment: Just FYI, the full code is located in https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/blob/master/src/AwsClient.php